# Is it possible using Resharper to remove an object initializer?

Tags: c#-3.0, resharper

Resharper 4.5 has the ability to turn the contstuction of an object followed by the setting of properties on that object into the object initializer format.

My question is can it go the other way and remove the user of an object initializer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about 4.5 specifically, but Resharper can currently (v7-8) do this - put your cursor on the opening brace of the object initializer, hit `alt+enter`, and select "`to assignment statements`"

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOzqkPU5Ilw) shows you how.